# I want to be able to link multiple headings to reveal certain text

Tags: html, text, drop-down-menu

The HTML coding that I have so far works fine when you link to one place. However I want to link it so that you can click 'America' and you have to further click if you want 'north' or 'south' regions to drop down. However when you click on 'North' or 'South' nothing appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
lastone='empty'; 
function showIt(lyr) 
{ 
if (lastone!='empty') lastone.style.display='none'; 
lastone=document.getElementById(lyr); 
lastone.style.display='block';
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('divID')" ">England</a>
<div id="divID" style="display:none;">
List of stockists for England
</div>
<BR>
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div1')" ">America</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
</script>

<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div2')" ">North</a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
List of Stockists
</div>
<BR>
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div3')" ">South</a>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">
List of Stockists
</div>`<script type="text/javascript">
lastone='empty'; 
function showIt(lyr) 
{ 
if (lastone!='empty') lastone.style.display='none'; 
lastone=document.getElementById(lyr); 
lastone.style.display='block';
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('divID')" ">England</a>
<div id="divID" style="display:none;">
List of stockists for England
</div>
<BR>
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div1')" ">America</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
</script>

<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div2')" ">North</a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
List of Stockists
</div>
<BR>
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div3')" ">South</a>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">
List of Stockists
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot o errors in you code closed scripts that never be openes, an '"' never opened too: (onClick="showIt('div2')" ") for example.

If you don't restore "lastone" to "empty" when you press on "North" all "America" div gets display none again, so this works, you have to play with it...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    lastone='empty';

    function showIt(lyr)
    {
        if (lastone !='empty') lastone.style.display='none';

        lastone=document.getElementById(lyr);
        lastone.style.display='block';
        lastone = "empty";
    }

</script>
<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('divID')">England</a>
<div id="divID" style="display:none;">
List of stockists for England
</div>
<BR>

<a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div1')">America</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
    <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div2')">North</a>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
        List of Stockists
    </div>
    <BR>

    <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="showIt('div3')">South</a>
    <div id="div3" style="display:none;">
        List of Stockists
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful and has come in extremely handy.

Comment: However I have another problem in that I now want to add more than 2 drop downs to the America wording - North, West, Mid West and South. However when I duplicate the coding to add in the extra drop downs they aren't linking to America. 

Please help.

Comment: Please post your code for a right an useful help ;)